# Razor View - Multiple Forms Formatting

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

First post, please go easy! Technology - .netcore, c#, razor page.

I am building a smiley face review. Using razor to build the form(s), the smiley images get stacked vertically, not so great - so I have a formatting issue. The issue is to stack the form elements from block to display-inline (but this is using razor to build the form elements).

The code functionality works just fine. Built a Smiley class into the Model folder. Brought it into a razor page, targeted an asp-action and passed the chosen outcome to a receiving page. All good.

However, in the razor view, I brought in the Smiley class:

```
@{
 @model ****.Models.Smiley
}
```

The lines of code below, stack the form elements vertically. I want horizontal.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReviewActionTrials3", "Home", new { mySelection = Smiley.Sentiment.Sad                   }, FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/sad.png" alt="Submit Sad">
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ReviewActionTrials3", "Home", new { mySelection = Smiley.Sentiment.Happy}, FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="image"  src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/happy.png" alt="Submit Sad">
}
```

Tried all kinds of advice, but couldn't achieve my requirement.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are block-level elements and will stack vertically by default. Change their display to inline (and use tag helpers, not HTML helpers)

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ReviewActionTrials3" style="display-inline">
```

Or instead of setting the style explicitly, if you are using Bootstrap, use the `d-inline` CSS class:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ReviewActionTrials3" class="d-inline">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReviewActionTrials3", "Home", new { mySelection = Smiley.Sentiment.Sad                   }, FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/sad.png" alt="Submit Sad">
}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReviewActionTrials3", "Home", new { mySelection = Smiley.Sentiment.Happy}, FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="image"  src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/happy.png" alt="Submit Sad">
}
    </div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127700/how-to-get-rows-of-a-form-to-display-horizontally-in-razor-pages)  to know more.

Comment: Thank you. Can work with this. Thank you very much for answering my question. Much appreciated Qing Guo.